# How to have my docker daemon log print to logfile not to STDOUT?

Tags: docker

When I start my docker daemon with `service docker start` or `docker -d`, I usually get my shell terminal. But when there's docker daemon log need to be output, log is printed directly on my screen and I lost my shell terminal. I press ENTER and get shell terminal again. I don't want this. Printing docker daemon log into log files will be better to me. How to print my docker log into logfiles rather than STDOUT?

Comment: Which platform is this on (e.g. Ubuntu, Centos) ?

Comment: CentOS 6.5,  but why it matters

Comment: Because the 'service start' implementation is different for different platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix has a concept of 'redirection', so you can ask stdout to go to a file instead using a command like this:

```
docker -d > my_logfile
```

(you would probably also want to redirect stderr)

Now,a more complicated version of this is exactly what the docker service [startup script](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/2767509894e52f7ff28bdd95ccc7737eb6779a1a/contrib/init/sysvinit-debian/docker#L108) does:

```
start-stop-daemon [...] >> "$DOCKER_LOGFILE" 2>&1
```

so I'm not sure why you are seeing output to your terminal if you use that route.

Comment: `docker -d >> my_logfile 2>&1` should work but it looks a long command to type, it will be better to configure logfile path in docker config if has one.

Comment: And `/var/log/docker` is the log file written automaticly, of course I can use `docker -d > /dev/null 2>&1`.